# Memleak using Streamreader

Tags: c#, file, memory-leaks, streamreader

I was just trying to programmatically analyze a file when I found something strange (prob. did a mistake somewhere).
I got a list of files, opening on after another and analyzing the contents of those files.
When I do this I get crazy amounts of memory usage even tho I'm not trying to save anything.

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
    using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //do some checks
        sr.Close(); //do I have to do this?
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, lets say I'm checking 5 files. Each files size is 500mb.
With this method my program would take around 2.5gb memory even tho I'm pretty sure I'm closing the file/stream with the `using` and also the `sr.Close();`.

I've tried to not use `.ReadToEnd()` but that makes it very very slow.
Also I tried closing the stream with `using` aswell as `.Close()`.
I tried `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file)`.

I prob. got a thinking mistake somewhere so I would really appreciate anything that puts me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!
Greets Myridor

Comment: You don't need to close it manually because that `using` statement guarantees that `Dispose()` will be called, and `Dispose()`  and `Close()` do the same thing. Anyway, disposing the reader doesn't magically make the garbage collector collect the memory used by the string. If you want to minimise memory usage, read the file in chunks.

Comment: My guess is your _'// do some checks'_ logic may be doing work with strings that may be causing your problem. Strings are immutable and depending on how and what you are doing with them this could be where your issue is. [Immutability of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#immutability-of-strings), _All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object._

Comment: How are you checking how much RAM you are using? Windows will automatically cache in memory any file you open, so if you have plenty spare RAM it's not surprising. None of this RAM is fully committed, it'll be released if someone else needs it. Likewise any memory that GC is holding can be released fairly quickly.

Comment: `string s = sr.ReadToEnd();` is going to allocate a string with the same length of the file. Do that enough times and you'll use a lot of memory. Of course the garbage collector will eventually trigger and allow that memory to be reused, but only if you don't keep any references to those strings alive. Since we can't see your `StreamReader` version, we can't help you understand why it was slower.

Comment: Just as an experiment. Try putting GC.Collect() after the `using` block. If the memory gets reclaimed, then you don't have a leak. Remove GC.Collect() after and trust that the GC will eventually reclaim it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do this I get crazy amounts of memory usage even tho I'm not trying to save anything.

You cannot check for memory leaks by just checking the memory of the process, since this will include garbage that is ready for cleanup. The runtime till do garbage collection when it needs memory. If you have lots of ram in your system it might decide to just request more memory from the OS instead of.

You should use a memory profiler to investigate memory issues, this should have a function to force a GC in an application and monitor the usage. If you think that is to complicated you could just add a `GC.Collec()t` to your loop, but you should probably remote it after you are done testing.

If you are using `using` you do not need to explicitly close the file, that should be done by the Dispose method in any reasonable API.

The `//do some checks` might keep a reference to the string that may cause high usage. That might be intentional, or constitute a memory leak. Use a memory profiler to check for if any large strings are retained.

But if the goal is to minimize the memory usage you should try to rewrite your code to stream data instead. I.e. read the file line by line, or into a reused buffer, and do all the processing you need to do on that line, possibly parsing data into some more compact representation. But this approach is not always feasible.

Comment: Okay so, I had the "problem" even without doing any checks! But as most of you guys already answered it's the garbage collection. When I use `GC.Collect()` after I'm done with each file the memory doesn't add up to such great amounts. Thank you all for the answers, for my testing I'm gonna use `GC.Collect()` but when I'm done I'm going to remove it!